# how to find combinations of elements with minimum length of N using itertools-Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools

```
from itertools import combinations
a = [1,2,3]
combinations(a,2) #will give me ((1,2),(1,3),(2,3))
combinations(a,3) #will give me ((1,2,3),)
```

but what if I want results of different length which is in a array
e.g.

I want to find all combinations of given array[1,2,3] of length more than or equal to 2
so result should be `((1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(1,2,3))`

something like  `c = combinations(a,>=2)`
I tried to use lambda but its not working

`c = combinations(a,lambda x: x for x in [2,3])`

as well list comprehensive `c = combinations(a,[x for x in [2,3]])`

I know I can use a simple loop and then find out the combinations of diff length.

```
for l in [2,3]:
    combinations(a,l)
```

But Is there any pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could combine `combinations` and [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain, combinations
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> n = 2
>>> cc = chain.from_iterable(combinations(a, i) for i in range(n, len(a)+1))
>>> list(cc)
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

`chain.from_iterable` here is flattening what the generator expression `(combinations(a, i) for i in range(n, len(a)+1))` is producing.  Otherwise you'd wind up with something like

```
>>> [list(combinations(a,i)) for i in range(n, len(a)+1)]
[[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3)]]
```

which is fine, but not quite in the format you were looking for.

Comment: this is quite nicely put

Comment: This is exactly what the [`powerset` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) uses, too.